# Seemingly random tika performance issues

Tags: java, rx-java, apache-tika

I use RxJava to pipe documents from a source to tika and from tika to ElasticSearch.

At some point in time tika takes about *5* minutes to index a document and continues normally afterwards.

I am unable to properly point out the cause: If I restart the application, everything is still the same, let's say it took 5mins at the 301st document last time, it will take 5mins at the 301st document again. But if I change up the order of the documents, it happens neither at the same index (301), nor with the same document (the previous 301st).

Here are the relevant parts of the application:

```java
public Indexable analyze(Indexable indexable) {
        Timestamp from = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        if (indexable instanceof NCFile) {
        // there is some code here that has no effect

            Metadata md = this.generateMetadata(((NCFile) indexable).getPath());
            ((NCFile) indexable).setType(md.get("Content-Type"));

            if (((NCFile) indexable).getType().startsWith("text/")) {
                ((NCFile) indexable).setContent(this.parseContent(((NCFile) indexable).getPath())); //todo . hier könnte man noch viel mehr machen
            } else {
                ((NCFile) indexable).setContent("");
            }
            ((NCFile) indexable).setType(this.detectMediaType(((NCFile) indexable).getPath()));

    }
        Timestamp to = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("the file " + ((NCFile) indexable).getPath() + " took " + (to.getTime()-from.getTime()) + " ms to parse");
        return indexable;
    }
```

and the pipeline that is feeding the code above:

```java
nc.filter(action -> action.getOperation() == Operation.INSERT)
                .map(IndexingAction::getIndexable)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                .map(indexableAction -> metadataAnalyzer.analyze(indexableAction))
                .map(indexable -> {
                    indexer.insert(indexable);
                    return indexable;
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map(indexable -> "The indexable " + indexable.getIdentifier() + " of class " + indexable.getClass().getName() + " has been inserted.")
                .subscribe(message -> this.logger.log(Level.INFO, message));
```

My guess would be that the problem is memory- or thread-related; but as far as I can see, the code should work perfectly fine.

```
the file Workspace/xx/xx-server/.test-documents/testRFC822_base64 took 5 ms to index
the file Workspace/xx/xx-server/.test-documents/testPagesHeadersFootersAlphaLower.pages took 306889 ms to index
the file Workspace/xx/xx-server/.test-documents/testFontAfterBufferedText.rtf took 2 ms to index
the file Workspace/xx/xx-server/.test-documents/testOPUS.opus took 7 ms to index
```

Funny thing is, these are the tika testfiles provided in their repo.

EDIT:
After a request I looked into it using FR, but I am not sure what exactly I have to look at:

Right after the plateau it stops working, even though neither the RAM nor the CPU limit is met

[image]

EDIT 2:
Is it the PipedReader that is blocking alle of these threads? Do I understand that correctly?

[image]

EDIT 3:

Here is a 1min flight recording:

Note: The flight recording seems wrong. In my system monitor application I do not see such a big memory consumption (apparent 16GB?!)...

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you attach Flight Recorder and see what the code does?

Comment: High CPU usage, high GC activity, when you see the slow file, record 1 minute of it and then see what hot methods are hot.

Comment: Also are you running with the default 256MB memory? Maybe raise Xmx to 1G?

Comment: already at 1g...

Comment: @akarnokd added the flight recording

Comment: That doesn't tell me much. Do you have the view for hot methods? Also what else is running on that machine so you maxed out the RAM?

Comment: As I said, RAM is *not* maxed out -- i have no idea why the flight recorder is telling this. RAM might be *used* at 100%, but the ram is allocated as swap (unix-system) and therefore "used" at a 100% (still available, though)... I will try to get some hot method intel. All I can say is, that PipedReader is suddenly blocking all Threads, but I have no idea what that means (I'm not that big of a Java guy...)

Comment: Also, Tika is used as a library, the files are the tika test files so I strongly suspect the problem does not ly with tika.

Comment: Could you post a standalone project somewhere?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not allowed to do that. I can provide more of the code, if you need it... What are you suspecting is going wrong? What would be your guess/where would you start to debug? This could help me find the problem

Comment: Doubtful. Can't you just create a project that works on the tika demo files? How are you feeding values into the flow? Also since you detect the performance problem inside `analyze`, it is unlikely the problem is RxJava but one of those undisclosed this:: method calls you have.

Comment: I will look into the methods. If I cant figure out what causes this issue, I will try create a minimalistic working example. It is not that I don't *want* to share the project, I am not *allowed* to